# How to make a tab hidden until it is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code where when hover over the link tag ***.cat-link a.navlink*** below, each of the subcategory tab ***.subcategories div*** will display.

It works well but what I want is to hide all tabs. When I hover over a tab with the mouse and I want it show and when I remove the mouse I want it to hide.

The first tab shows even after i refresh the page.

Is there a way to make all the tab hidden or displayed none until i hover over it. Thanks

```js
const tabBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.category .cat-link .navlink');
const tab = document.querySelectorAll('.subcategories div');

        function tabShow(panelIndex) {
            tab.forEach(function(node) {
                node.style.display = "none";
            });
            tab[panelIndex].style.display = "block";
        }

        tabShow(0);
```

```css
.subcategories {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.subcategories div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat-link">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(0)" class="navlink computer">
          <i class="fa fa-tv"></i>
          <span>Computer & Gaming</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(1)" class="navlink phone">
          <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt"></i>
          <span>Mobiles & Tablets</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(2)" class="navlink elect">
          <i class="fa fa-computer-speaker"></i>
          <span>Electronics</span>
      </a> 
</div>

<div class="subcategories">
     <div class="computer-sub">
         1
     </div>
     <div class="mobile-sub">
         2
      </div>
     <div class="electronics-sub">
         3
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it, but to keep it simple and within the way you were trying to do it, you can simply divide your current `tabShow` function into 2 functions like `tabShow` and `tabHide`, have `tabShow` to include only the line of code that will actually display your stuff:

```
function tabShow(panelIndex) {
    tab[panelIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

And `tabHide` to hide your stuff:

```
function tabHide(panelIndex) {
    tab.forEach(function(node) {
        node.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

And don't forget to remove `tabShow(0);` from your JS!

Then add `onmouseout="tabHide()"` with each `onmouseover="tabShow(x)"` that you have.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const tabBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.category .cat-link .navlink');
const tab = document.querySelectorAll('.subcategories div');

        function tabShow(panelIndex) {
            tab[panelIndex].style.display = "block";
        }
        function tabHide(panelIndex) {
            tab.forEach(function(node) {
                node.style.display = "none";
            });
        }
```

```css
.subcategories {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.subcategories div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat-link">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(0)" onmouseout="tabHide()" class="navlink computer">
          <i class="fa fa-tv"></i>
          <span>Computer & Gaming</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(1)" onmouseout="tabHide()" class="navlink phone">
          <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt"></i>
          <span>Mobiles & Tablets</span>
      </a> 
      <a href="#" onmouseover="tabShow(2)" onmouseout="tabHide()" class="navlink elect">
          <i class="fa fa-computer-speaker"></i>
          <span>Electronics</span>
      </a> 
</div>

<div class="subcategories">
     <div class="computer-sub">
         1
     </div>
     <div class="mobile-sub">
         2
      </div>
     <div class="electronics-sub">
         3
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When an element has `display: none;` it has no bounding box which means you can't detect hovering.

Try using opacity instead.

```
const tabBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.category .cat-link .navlink');
const tab = document.querySelectorAll('.subcategories div');

function tabShow(panelIndex) {
    tab.forEach(function(node) {
        node.style.opacity = "0";
    });
    tab[panelIndex].style.opacity  = "1";
}

tabShow(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two different CSS class, the one has `visibility: hidden;` and the other has `visibility: visible;`. You can add/remove CSS class from any HTML element by using (e.g.) `node.classList.add("hidden-node");` and `node.classList.remove("show-node");`.